# How can I convert a video file (mpeg, for example) into a collection of images?

Tags: java, c++, video, mpeg

How can I convert a video file (mpeg, for example) into a collection of images?

Ideal answer would cover both C++ and Java using available libraries, and also how to manually strip the individual frames out of a video file for some common video format.

Comment: Current answer by Don Reba is good and I will accept it unless someone provides a more thorough one.  Clearly I can just look at ffmpeg's source code to see the details, but if there's a reference that's easier to read than raw source code that would be appreciated.  Also, is there any library in Java that does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To extract all frames losslessly, use

```
ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -f image2 "outdir/%05d.png"
```

If you prefer a different output format, just change `.png`; by default `ffmpeg` will infer the file type from the extension.

The option `-f image2` tells `ffmpeg` to write to a series of images. The `"outdir/%05d.png"` gives a filename pattern, in this case "`5-digit frame number.png`".

If you only want to extract *n* frames per second, add the option `-r n` after `"$input_file"`. (I think *n* can be floating-point.)

In the case that your video is Motion JPEG (mjpeg), instead use:

```
ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -vcodec copy -f image2 "outdir/%05d.jpg"
```

This unpacks the frames directly from the video stream, which is faster and obviously uses less disk space.

For more information/other options, see the man page or [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html) (search for `image2`).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) with `-vcodec png`. For example, this would convert my_video.avi into frames with five-digit numbers:

> ffmpeg -i my_video.avi -vcodec png frame%05d.png

You can also need to specify desired framerate and resolution. You can run `ffmpeg -codecs` to see all the available formats.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad it's so easy.

Comment: Have you tried this and you're sure it works?  Does it support jpg, gif, bmp?

Comment: I tried it. You can run `ffmpeg -codecs` to see what's supported. Gif and bmp seem to be there; not sure about jpg.

Comment: Yes, I use ffmpeg too for converting a video to image files. I use subprocess in python for calling ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `apiexample.c` inside the ffmpeg's `libavcodec` library that will allow you to see how to take a frame buffer to encode it in the mpeg stream easily.

Alternatively you can use [Gstreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) which is a much neater framework.

For Java, try to use [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html).